# Solr Custom Schema Questions

Tags: solr

I'm new to solr and working on a project and need to index a collection of XML documents with the following format:

```
<data>
  <StoryRecord ID="12345">
    <Title>title here</Title>
    <Category>general</Category>
    <Story>Lorem ipsem .... etc</Story>
 </StoryRecord>
</data>
```

My question is two-fold: how can I relate something like `<StoryRecord><Title>` to `<field name="Title" ... />` in the schema? And, how can I grab an attribute with copyField, like StoryRecord@ID, as my `<field name="id" ... />`? (Am I first required to reformat the data before I can use my documents as input?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to transform your XML documents in some way or the other, as Solr expects update messages in a specific XML format (or JSON, etc. - depending on the Update Handler used).

The best way to do this for arbitary XML is probably to use the [XSLTUpdateRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/XsltUpdateRequestHandler), which is built to transform custom XML into Solr's XML-based update format.

There's an example XSL available in `example/solr/collection1/conf/xslt/updateXml.xsl` in the default distribution. See the last example at the [XSLTUpdateRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/XsltUpdateRequestHandler) page for how to submit an XML document and how to specify which XSL to use (`&tr=filename.xsl`).

Comment: Thank you, sir. I was hoping I could skip an intermediate transform step but I guess I'll have to revitalize my XSLT skills.